# all images moving together if I change margin left of individual

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make slider of three images for that purpose I make ul li inside a div and trying to move individual li by changing margin left in console but it moves all images together. Please correct me where I am wrong. See the code below

```css
#slider{
    width: 311px;
    height: 333px;
    overflow:hidden;     
    }

    #slider .slides{
    display: block;
    width: 311px;
    height:333px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }

    #slider . slide{
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    list-style-type: none;
    width:311px;
    height:333px;    
    }
```

```html
<div id='slider'>            
            <ul class='slides'>
                <li class='slide'><img src='images/a.jpe'></li>
                <li class='slide'><img src='images/b.jpe'></li>
                <li class='slide'><img src='images/c.jpe'></li>                
            </ul>                        
</div>
```

Comment: try to using applying padding in li tag..

Comment: please attach the console command that fails

Comment: padding for what Mukesh

Comment: and there is no error in console yossi

Comment: it's just moving images altogether instead one by one by using margin-left: 50px;  It should move the one i move only.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? Also remove the space between `.` and `slide` in `#slider . slide` that is incorrect syntax. P.S when an element is absolutely positioned, `float` will be irrelevant.

Comment: I am trying to make a slider with jquery and I want to move images one by one. For that I thought to change margin left

Comment: removing space where you specified, almost works for me thank you Aziz

Comment: @mohsin i can't understand HOW you are trying to use the console for that purpose. the code, as you attached here - is applied to all elements.. so try to elaborate HOW do you want to move the elements.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
li.slide:nth-of-type(2) {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

This was moving the second li element only.